# Reload tableview after Search Bar (ModernSearchBar)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have this pod successfully setup on my app (Modernsearchbar)
It retrieves correctly a result when I search on my tableview (it launch successfully this func)

```
func onClickItemWithUrlSuggestionsView(item: ModernSearchBarModel) {
        print("User touched this item: "+item.title+" with this url: "+item.url.description)
}
```

But I don't know how to go back to my Tableview only with the result (with my tableview reloaded)
When I try, i cannot dismiss the ModernSearchBar.

If someone has any clue, I would like or :

- checkmark my result and dismiss the modernSearchBar

Or

- dismiss the modernSearchBar and reload my TableView with only the result of the search.

Thanks in advance, I have been reading a lot here but didn't find any solution..

Answer (score 0):

To help if anyone has this question :

```
 My_ModernSearch.searchBarCancelButtonClicked(My_ModernSearch)
```

And for checkmark, take this :

```
for x in (0..<totalNumberOfRows).reversed() {

            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: x, section: 0)
            let cell = MyFriendsTableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            var MyFriendsLine: MyFriendsModel
            MyFriendsLine = self.MyFriendslist[indexPath.row]

            if(MyFriendsLine.field1 == item.title) {

                if cell?.accessoryType == .checkmark {
                    cell?.accessoryType = .none
                     }
             else {
                cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark

            }
```